# how to get list of standard folders with fs.readdir

Tags: node.js, windows, macos

I'm using node.js for something. I need to read all files and folders inside specific path and return standard "folders". for example when I give "MAC HD" as the path I like to get "Applications", "Library, "System", "Users" as result. I need to get all folders that are not hidden. in Windows, I have the same problem. I need Standard Folders or regular unhidden and not system folders.

this is my entire code :

```
const child = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

const currentPlatform = () => {
  if ('darwin' === os.platform()) {
    return 'MAC';
  } else {
    return 'WIN';
  }
};

const getDriveList = (data, emitter) => {
  const thisPlatform = currentPlatform();
  if (thisPlatform === 'WIN') {
    child.exec('wmic logicaldisk get name', (error, stdout) => {
      let winDriveList = stdout
        .split('\r\r\n')
        .filter(value => /[A-Za-z]:/.test(value))
        .map(value => value.trim());
      emitter('getDriveList', winDriveList);
    });
  } else {
    fs.readdir('/Volumes', (err, files) => {
      emitter('getDriveList', files);
    });
  }
};

const getFilesList = (path, emitter) => {
  console.log("this was sent from client ===>> ", path);
  fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    emitter('getFileList', files);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if such a thing exists, how do you define "standard folders"? It sounds like you just want to get the list of directories under `/` in mac and on windows you may need to dig through the registry for what you're looking for.

You can use [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) to get details about a given path, whether it is a directory vs. a file.

```
fs.stat('/Users', (err, stats) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (stats.isDirectory()) console.log("Its a directory!");
});
```

Nodejs doesn't expose a way to detect hidden files by default, you could try using the [hidefile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hidefile) library which has some platform specific logic for detecting if the file is hidden or not.

```
hidefile.isHidden("/Users", function(err, result) {
   if (err == null) console.log(result);  //-> false
});
```

Comment: about standard folder! I mean folders that are not hidden!

Comment: Then just use the `fs.stat` and `fs.readdir` functions to find the directories then use the `hidefile` library to detect if its hidden or not.